# Выборка из таблицы БД с помощью реляционной алгебры

Tags: sql, база-данных

Есть таблица БД состоящая из 3 столбцов, к примеру Повар, Блюдо, Клиент. И есть задание, мол: нужно получить номер повара, готовящий одно и то же блюдо для всех клиентов. Желательно реляционной алгеброй, либо просто связкой запросов в sql. Т.е.:

Повар  | Блюдо | Клиент
П1     |Б1      |К1
П1     |Б1      |К2
П2     |Б1      |К1
П2     |Б1      |К2
П2     |Б2      |К2
П3     |Б1      |К1
П3     |Б3      |К1
П3     |Б2      |К2

Здесь ответ должен быть П1 и П2, т.к. они делают одно и то же блюдо для всех клиентов (несмотря на то, что П2 делает еще и Б2 для К2).
Сколько бы я не думал и не читал про объединения и прочее, я не смог найти нормального ответа насчет того, как это сделать.

Comment: Уникальных блюд у каждого повара может быть и по 2 и по 10. К примеру, у П1 есть Б1-К1, Б2-К1, Б3-К1, Б4-К1 | Б2-К2, Б3-К2 | Б3-К3 | Б3-К4 | Б3-К5 | Б3-К6. всего 4 уникальных блюд и 6 уникальных клиентов, при этом блюдо Б3 готовится для всех 6ти клиентов.

В первом примере ваш запрос взял бы лишь П1 без П2.

Comment: как мне кажется у Вас не рационально хранятся данные)

Comment: @Maksim Не внимательно прочитал вопрос ... Тогда делаем join между двумя подзапросами. Первый получает количество уникальных клиентов для связок Повар-Блюдо. А второй - количество уникальных клиентов для повара в целом. Те повара у которых есть блюдо по которому количество клиентов совпадает с количеством клиентов у повара в целом и есть искомые.

Comment: Да, такой вариант вполне рабочий, если его попробовать оформить в виде запроса, то получается нечто вроде:
`select P 
from Table_1 
group by P
having (select count(distinct B))=(select count(distinct K))`
Отправьте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.